# How to use Pyramid with Tornado

Tags: python, tornado, pyramid

I have an application written using Pyramid web framework. But I need asynchronously functionality for WebSockets. This is functionality implemented in Tornado. And I try use of the Pyramid with Tornado like this:

```
app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/', IndexHandler),
])

def build_tornado_app():
    app.listen(6544)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

# This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application
def main(global_config, **settings):
    build_tornado_app()
    # ... config routes, database session etc.
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Unfortunately, starting Tornado application (using start() function) is blocking chain of execution.

Could I start Tornado app without blocking Pyramid chain of execution?

Answer (score 2):

To use the asynchronous features of Tornado (including websockets), you must use Tornado's HTTPServer instead of running it in a WSGI container. You can then run Pyramid inside of Tornado using [tornado.web.WSGIContainer](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer), replacing your current WSGI container entirely.

However, Tornado's WSGIContainer is single-threaded, which is not a good choice for most applications built with a WSGI framework. Unless you have a strong need to run Pyramid and Tornado in the same process I recommend keeping them separate, running a pure-Tornado websocket process alongside your Pyramid app.

Comment: After investigation I also think that running Pyramid and Tornado into one process is a bad idea.